# MVC5: can we replace Ninject with ASP.Net Core dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ninject

We have a large MVC5 application that makes extensive use of Ninject. We're having some performance problems and would like to replace Ninject with a more performant framework. We're not planning to migrate the project to Core any time soon. Is it possible or advisable to try to use the Core dependency injection components? If not, which dependency injection frameworks would be the most natural "drop in" replacement for Ninject?

Comment: It primarily depends on your Ninject usage. For example, if you are using interceptors intensively - there is no such feature in built-in .Net Core DI.

Comment: The `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package can be used in 'normal' .NET applications as well, but you should look at the features you need (or might need in the future) to decide whether moving to this minimalistic container implementation is suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks - we're almost exclusively using Ninject to perform constructor injection to MVC controllers. The services we're injecting are all in either Singleton scope or Request scope. Sometimes they have constructor arguments.

Comment: Sure! Give it a whirl and let us know if you run into problems.